# PHP - How to combine / merge multiple pdf's

Tags: php, pdf

I have some pdf documents on a linux server that I want to combine together to form one document using PHP 5?

Does anyone know if this can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can invoke the command-line utility [`pdfjam`](https://github.com/rrthomas/pdfjam), which can be easily installed on most Unix-like systems.

Comment: PDF Jam link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

## <strike>use GS</strike>

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=finished.pdf file1.pdf file2.pdf
```

taken from: http://mylinuxnotes.wordpress.com/2007/09/19/howto-join-pdf-files/
documentation: https://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/8229-putting-together-pdf-files

### pdftk - Why NOT?

pdftk uses too many dependencies (and java!!! :O). For this task you can avoid this by using gs.

---

pdftk better :D merges faster.
i have 600pdf and pdtfk took ~11sec, while gs 6min 
maybe there is some gs options, but pdftk simpler (bow)