# Merge PDF files with PHP

Tags: php, pdf

My concept is - there are 10 pdf files in a website. User can select some pdf files and then select merge to create a single pdf file which contains the selected pages. How can i do this with php?

Comment: Related question (answered btw): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713701/php-how-to-combine-merge-multiple-pdfs

Comment: @Webnet actually, 64% is ok. I'd say 0 - 25% = fail, but I guess that's where it gets subjective

Comment: Can you use a command line tool?

Comment: Can you use Zend Framework? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254218/merging-2-pdf-with-zend-framework

Comment: Where can i find "pdftk-112-1i386.rpm" file and how to install it to the server?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I've done this before. I had a pdf that I generated with fpdf, and I needed to add on a variable amount of PDFs to it.

So I already had an fpdf object and page set up (http://www.fpdf.org/)
And I used fpdi to import the files (http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/)
FDPI is added by extending the PDF class:

```
class PDF extends FPDI
{

} 



    $pdffile = "Filename.pdf";
    $pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($pdffile);  
    for($i=0; $i<$pagecount; $i++){
        $pdf->AddPage();  
        $tplidx = $pdf->importPage($i+1, '/MediaBox');
        $pdf->useTemplate($tplidx, 10, 10, 200); 
    }
```

This basically makes each pdf into an image to put into your other pdf. It worked amazingly well for what I needed it for.

Comment: I cannot understand your code. can you please explain some more detail? I also did not find "setSourceFile" and "importPage" functions in fpdf manual.

Comment: I went back and looked at my solution a little more in detail. I hope this is more helpful. I completely forgot about the fdpi part this morning when I wrote this, its one small part of a pretty complicated PDF generator I wrote.

Comment: @Christa Beware that FPDI will only parse certain PDF files. I'm running into a problem where FPDI won't parse PDF files above v 1.4 and FPDI is making me buy their parser to handle > v1.4... yar....

Comment: Don't you think it's better to do $i = 0 and $i <= $pagecount.

It makes it better to read i think.

Great example btw, really helped me

Comment: `This basically makes each pdf into an image to put into your other pdf.` that is not quite true, its not converting the pdf into an image. Text is still selectable.

Answer (score 153):

Below is the php code to merge pdf using Ghostscript command.

```
$fileArray= array("name1.pdf","name2.pdf","name3.pdf","name4.pdf");

$datadir = "save_path/";
$outputName = $datadir."merged.pdf";

$cmd = "gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=$outputName ";
//Add each pdf file to the end of the command
foreach($fileArray as $file) {
    $cmd .= $file." ";
}
$result = shell_exec($cmd);
```

I forgot the link from where I found it, but it works fine.

Note: You should have gs (on linux and probably Mac), or Ghostscript (on windows) installed for this to work.

Comment: It worked for me without problems and without installing external libraries as FPDI or others.

Comment: This solution worked best for me. It was very easy to install Ghostscript on my server. It was just "yum install ghostscript". And your script worked perfectly

Comment: This merged my PDF's but unfortunately stripped all the data from the fillable fields and also broke the fields themselves.

Comment: I am getting a blank pdf page :(

Comment: 2016 here, this thing still works like a charm. For people having a white page, you need to give the full adress on your file (name1.pdf -> blabla/n/qkjsdfgh/name1.pdf)

Comment: It is working very fine. But I am getting and problem. In my pdf I have bullets using &bull; but when I merge using command they  converted into square.Please help if any one can

Comment: I have two pdf and both are open properly but when combine using your coding and that time I am getting blank page 

Can you please help me in the same?

Comment: How long does this take, lets say you have ten 1,000 page documents and want to merge them, would this take 2 seconds or 2 minutes?

Comment: 2017 and it works kinda. I am finding that Macs have better luck running the script. Windows based machines are generating white pages but only sometimes. What might be causing this?

Comment: You need Ghostscript installed, otherwise it fails silently.

Comment: How I do this with base64encoded sting. it is not saved on the disc.

Comment: I am getting this message **** Unable to open the initial device, quitting.

Comment: You should explain what it actually does. It actually is not really a php way to do the task, in php you only prepare data and then you execute a shell script, which does the actual task. also you should include in your answer, that gs (on linux and probably Mac), or Ghostscript (on windows) should be installed for this to work.. Still i quite like this solution, as gs is included in Ubuntu by default i think, i did not have to install it.

Comment: Also i think this could be a link to original solution: www.codeexpertz.com.prox.science/blog/php/php-merge-multiple-pdf-files-single-pdfresolving-timeout-error

Comment: Script works, just a suggestion, Instead of `foreach` loop you may use `implode` function of PHP, it will save one loop

Comment: @NishadUp try absolute paths for both input and output file.

Comment: if you set all the path as absolute path and you have ghostscript installed. this works like a charm

Comment: @NishadUp brother have you solved that issues saying "**** Unable to open the initial device, quitting." . please let me know i am getting guide me how to solve it?

Comment: Worked like a charm, struggling since hours with FPDI not working. Nedd to install imagemagick on linux tho, but still a better way to do that installing third party php libs...

Comment: This worked great! You might need to add the full path to gs in order to work: /usr/bin/gs

Answer (score 50):

i suggest **PDFMerger** from [github.com](https://github.com/clegginabox/pdf-merger), so easy like ::

```
include 'PDFMerger.php';

$pdf = new PDFMerger;

$pdf->addPDF('samplepdfs/one.pdf', '1, 3, 4')
    ->addPDF('samplepdfs/two.pdf', '1-2')
    ->addPDF('samplepdfs/three.pdf', 'all')
    ->merge('file', 'samplepdfs/TEST2.pdf'); // REPLACE 'file' WITH 'browser', 'download', 'string', or 'file' for output options
```

Comment: This is basically someone's implementation of @Christa's answer (FPDF+FDPI), which is great :) Thanks!

Comment: It does work on some PDF's really well, but some of the code is now deprecated.

Comment: Its also doesn't work with some types of compression on some PDF's.

Comment: Using this with DOMPDF and it works a charm thank you!

Comment: I am getting "FPDF error: Unable to find xref table." any solution for that?

Comment: @Sameeraa4ever google it, the solution* is on the first result :P

Comment: It works but sometime shows error below...

FPDF error: This document (samplepdfs/four.pdf) probably uses a compression technique which is not supported by the free parser shipped with FPDI.

Comment: For PDFs of version 1.5 or higher you need a paid version of the fpdi library used by this solution (per the error cited by @Nikhil )

Comment: The original PDFMerger project (not the clone linked above) appears to have moved away from the commercial fpdi library: https://github.com/myokyawhtun/PDFMerger

Comment: this does not work for images, if you have picture in your sources, it wont get copied

Comment: @Matthew how to use dompdf for merging 2 files?

Comment: I have used https://github.com/myokyawhtun/PDFMerger instead of https://github.com/clegginabox/pdf-merger, but do notice that myokyawhtun throws errors in PHP8.2 right now.

Answer (score 13):

```
$cmd = "gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=".$new." ".implode(" ", $files);
shell_exec($cmd);
```

A simplified version of Chauhan's answer

Comment: This worked fine for me on hostgator centos dedicated server so ghostscript must already be installed

Comment: Should be marked as a correct answer too, because it was so damn EASY. Hours struggling with FPDF and FPDI not loading correctly. You saved my life. Just need to install "imagemagick" (on debian/ubuntu : apt install imagemagick) on the server and it's ok. Cheers !

Answer (score 11):

Both the accepted answer and even the FDPI homepage seem to give botched or incomplete examples.  Here's mine which works and is easy to implement.  As expected it requires fpdf and fpdi libraries:

- FPDF: http://www.fpdf.org/en/download.php
- FPDI: https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/downloads

```php
require('fpdf.php');
require('fpdi.php');

$files = ['doc1.pdf', 'doc2.pdf', 'doc3.pdf'];

$pdf = new FPDI();

// iterate over array of files and merge
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($file);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $pageCount; $i++) {
        $tpl = $pdf->importPage($i + 1, '/MediaBox');
        $pdf->addPage();
        $pdf->useTemplate($tpl);
    }
}

// output the pdf as a file (http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm)
$pdf->Output('F','merged.pdf');
```

Comment: Hi @billynoah
I like this but it does  not work on landscape and seems to only merge the 1st pages.

Comment: @GeraldoIsaaks - I subsequently added support for multipage documents in my own application.  I've updated the answer.  Not sure about landscape issues - I haven't run into that.

Comment: What's butched on [this](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/demos/concatenate-fake/) examle which is available since the early days of FPDI?

Comment: @Setasign - I've never seen that but thanks for sharing.

Comment: @billynoah Thanks for the clear and updated simple code example here in SO. It got me started. I ended up using more of the code from the setasign example (https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/demos/concatenate-fake/, link is easy to miss in comment above). Their logic inside the addPage call made my particular concatenated pages look better. Probably also handles portrait/landscape better although I didn't test that. But I didn't find the example with searches and didn't know I was interested till I saw your answer.

Answer (score 5):

I've had similar problem in my software. We've wanted to merge several PDF files into one PDF file and submit it to an outer service. We've been using the FPDI solution as shown in **Christa**'s solution.

However, the input PDF's we've been using could be in version higher than 1.7. We've decided to evaluate the FPDI commercial add-on. However, it turned out that some of the documents scanned by our office copier were having malformed indexes, which crashed the commercial FPDI add-on. So we've decided to use **Ghostscript** solution as in **Chauhan**'s answer.

But then we got some strange metadata in the output PDF properties.

Finally we've decided to join two solutions to get PDF's merged and downgraded by Ghostscript, but the metadata is set by FPDI. We don't know yet how it would work with some advanced formatted pdfs, but for scans we use it works just fine. Here's our class excerpt:

```
class MergedPDF extends \FPDI
{
    private $documentsPaths = array();

    public function Render()
    {
        $outputFileName = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'merged');

        // merge files and save resulting file as PDF version 1.4 for FPDI compatibility
        $cmd = "/usr/bin/gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=$outputFileName";
        foreach ($this->getDocumentsPaths() as $pdfpath) {
            $cmd .= " $pdfpath ";
        }
        $result = shell_exec($cmd);
        $this->SetCreator('Your Software Name');
        $this->setPrintHeader(false);
        $numPages = $this->setSourceFile($outputFileName);
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $numPages; $i++) {
            $tplIdx = $this->importPage($i);
            $this->AddPage();
            $this->useTemplate($tplIdx);
        }

        unlink($outputFileName);

        $content = $this->Output(null, 'S');

        return $content;
    }

    public function getDocumentsPaths()
    {
        return $this->documentsPaths;
    }

    public function setDocumentsPaths($documentsPaths)
    {
        $this->documentsPaths = $documentsPaths;
    }

    public function addDocumentPath($documentPath)
    {
        $this->documentsPaths[] = $documentPath;
    }
}
```

The usage of this class is as follows:

```
$pdf = new MergedPDF();
$pdf->setTitle($pdfTitle);
$pdf->addDocumentPath($absolutePath1);
$pdf->addDocumentPath($absolutePath2);
$pdf->addDocumentPath($absolutePath3);
$tempFileName = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'merged');
$content = $pdf->Render();
file_put_contents($tempFileName, $content);
```

Comment: Just to mention, That I used the same code on Windows env. and don't forget to put program folder in " but not the parameters. `$cmd = "\"C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs9.20\\bin\\gswin64c.exe\" -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=[....your parameters...]" ; `

Answer (score 3):

I have tried similar issue and works fine, try it.  It can handle different orientations between PDFs.

```
    // array to hold list of PDF files to be merged
    $files = array("a.pdf", "b.pdf", "c.pdf");
    $pageCount = 0;
    // initiate FPDI
    $pdf = new FPDI();

    // iterate through the files
    foreach ($files AS $file) {
        // get the page count
        $pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($file);
        // iterate through all pages
        for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pageCount; $pageNo++) {
            // import a page
            $templateId = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);
            // get the size of the imported page
            $size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($templateId);

            // create a page (landscape or portrait depending on the imported page size)
            if ($size['w'] > $size['h']) {
                $pdf->AddPage('L', array($size['w'], $size['h']));
            } else {
                $pdf->AddPage('P', array($size['w'], $size['h']));
            }

            // use the imported page
            $pdf->useTemplate($templateId);

            $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
            $pdf->SetXY(5, 5);
            $pdf->Write(8, 'Generated by FPDI');
        }
    }
```

Comment: This gives `Undefined index: w`

Comment: make sure you have FPDF properly configured

Comment: the parameters for me were $size['width'] and $size['height'] instead of $size['w'] and $size['h']

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on Windows

1. download PDFtk free from https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/
2. drop folder (PDFtk) into the root of c:
3. add the following to your php code where $file1 is the location and name of the first PDF file, $file2 is the location and name of the second and $newfile is the location and name of the destination file

   ```
   $file1 = ' c:\\\www\\\folder1\\\folder2\\\file1.pdf';  
   $file2 = ' c:\\\www\\\folder1\\\folder2\\\file2.pdf';  
   $file3 = ' c:\\\www\\\folder1\\\folder2\\\file3.pdf';   

   $command =  'cmd /c C:\\\pdftk\\\bin\\\pdftk.exe '.$file1.$file2.$newfile;
   $result = exec($command);
   ```

Comment: There is a PHP wrapper that makes this much cleaner. See https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk

Comment: Note: PdfTK does not work with RHEL 7 or Cent OS 7

Comment: For me it only worked like this: `$command = "cmd /c C:\\pdftk\\bin\\pdftk.exe {$file1} {$file2} cat output {$new}";` Notice the additional **cat output**. See [PDFtk examples](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

I created an abstraction layer over FPDI (might accommodate other engines).
I published it as a Symfony2 bundle depending on a library, and as the library itself.

[The bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/docdigital/pdf-manager-bundle)

[The Library](https://packagist.org/packages/docdigital/pdf-manager)

usage:

```
public function handlePdfChanges(Document $document, array $formRawData)
{
    $oldPath = $document->getUploadRootDir($this->kernel) . $document->getOldPath();
    $newTmpPath = $document->getFile()->getRealPath();

    switch ($formRawData['insertOptions']['insertPosition']) {
        case PdfInsertType::POSITION_BEGINNING:
            // prepend 
            $newPdf = $this->pdfManager->insert($oldPath, $newTmpPath);
            break;
        case PdfInsertType::POSITION_END: 
            // Append
            $newPdf = $this->pdfManager->append($oldPath, $newTmpPath);
            break;
        case PdfInsertType::POSITION_PAGE: 
            // insert at page n: PdfA={p1; p2; p3}, PdfB={pA; pB; pC} 
            // insert(PdfA, PdfB, 2) will render {p1; pA; pB; pC; p2; p3} 
            $newPdf = $this->pdfManager->insert(
                    $oldPath, $newTmpPath, $formRawData['insertOptions']['pageNumber']
                );
            break;
        case PdfInsertType::POSITION_REPLACE: 
            // does nothing. overrides old file.
            return;
            break;
    }
    $pageCount = $newPdf->getPageCount();
    $newPdf->renderFile($mergedPdfPath = "$newTmpPath.merged");
    $document->setFile(new File($mergedPdfPath, true));
    return $pageCount;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

myokyawhtun's solution worked best for me (using PHP 5.4)

You will still get an error though - I resolved using the following:

Line 269 of fpdf_tpl.php - changed the function parameters to:

```
function Image($file, $x=null, $y=null, $w=0, $h=0, $type='', $link='',$align='', $resize=false, $dpi=300, $palign='', $ismask=false, $imgmask=false, $border=0) {
```

I also made this same change on line 898 of fpdf.php