# How can I merge more than one PDF in single PDF in PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I want to merge more than one PDF to Single PDF.

I am using `FPDF` library and any help woudl be appreciated.

Comment: Please use search before asking. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794435/merge-pdf-files-with-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes of course you can using your existing FPDF library.
See https://github.com/clegginabox/pdf-merger
Simple and awesome.