# attach/merge pdfs from mysql blob/POST upload

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, merge, blob

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Merge PDF files with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794435/merge-pdf-files-with-php)

I need help merging/attaching pdf files, that are uploaded by a user using a normal html form and POST upload processing via php.

The file(s) that are uploaded shall be attached/merged with the (already existing) pdf in the mysql row containing the pdf as a blob.

Right now I am using this could for uploading the files. Uploading works fine, but I can't get to merge them with the existing pdf.

Code Source:

```
http://www.johnboy.com/scripts/merge-pdf-files-with-php/merge.phps
```

Can anybody please point me in the right direction? thanks!

Comment: Not really. I read that post. My problem is getting the mysql blob merged with the user's pdf file(s). So I am interested in that specific mysql part.

Comment: just save blob to tmp file. merging part is same.

Comment: is file_get_contents the right way to do it? thanks

Comment: file_put_contents('blob.pdf', $blob_data);

Comment: `$lieferschein = file_get_contents('http://somehost/test.pdf');
move_uploaded_file($lieferschein, "tmp/bla.pdf");`

trying with a static file first, this isn't working. move_uploaded_file works with the pdf's from the input form tho...

Comment: thank you. file_put_contents works. trying with the blob now...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it worked for me:

Create a get.php to fetch the file from the database and echo it together with the headers:

```
header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$name");
echo $content;
```

Then you can fetch the pdf from another php like this:

```
$tmp = file_get_contents("http://somehost/get.php?table=test&id=$id");
file_put_contents("tmp/$id.pdf", $tmp);
```

Finally, if you take the code from the link in my question, simply change this line:

```
$command = "pdftk tmp/$id.pdf $command output $output";
```