# Prepending a page to a PDF with fpdf

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I am using fpdf to dynamically build a pdf and add some data to it. I now need to merge the created pdf with a different pdf so that the pdf Im merging with (which is a single page) is inserted as page 1 with the rest of the dynamically created pdf after it. Any ideas on how to use fpdf to do this?

Comment: are you want add an empty page between the each pdf that are merged to one?

Comment: I want to open a pdf, add some text, save it out as a new filename. Then merge that with a different pdf so that the pages are added to the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this [FPDI](http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/). This one is help you i think.

Answer (score 0):

There has been a similar question, where a user tries to merge 10 pdf files. The answers provide a PHP method and a shell method - either one should work. [Have a look!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794435/merge-pdf-files-with-php)