# GhostScript - Merge pdfs from different directories

Tags: php, ghostscript

I have to merge a number of pdf files, and am using the solution detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6288199/869177) to build a command to Ghostscript:

```
// $output_file_name = 'test_file_complete.pdf'
// $original_file = 'test_file.pdf'
// $append_files = array('../toappend/1.pdf', '../toappend/2.pdf', '../toappend/3.pdf', '../toappend/4.pdf')
public function merge_documents($output_file_name, $original_file, $append_files) 
{
    $cmd = "gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=$output_file_name ";

    $cmd .= $original_file . " ";

    foreach($append_files as $file) {
        $cmd .= $file . " ";
    }

    $result = shell_exec($cmd);
 }
```

The $cmd string I build is:

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=test_file_complete.pdf test_file.pdf ../toappend/1.pdf ../toappend/2.pdf ../toappend/3.pdf ../toappend/4.pdf
```

Note that the first file to be merged is in the current directory, and the others are up a level in another directory.

In the command line, when I navigate to the directory of the original file and run this, it works perfectly. However, in my function it fails with the message:

> (string) Error: /undefinedfilename in
>   (TEMP_quote_2014_09_05_13_16_04.pdf) Operand stack:
>
> Execution stack:    %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--
>   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push Dictionary stack:    --dict:1162/1684(ro)(G)--
>   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:77/200(L)-- Current allocation mode is local Last OS error: 2

If I run that code using only the files in the "toappend" directory, it will merge those fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I use absolute paths, this ceases to be an issue. It's no problem for me to do this, however [this info on how ghostscript finds files](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#Finding_files) might come in handy for people having a similar issue.