# How to convert full excel to PDF with maatwebsite?

Tags: laravel-4, phpexcel, mpdf

I make a report with maatwebsite and download it to xls and works fine, but now I need to export it to PDF, so when it exports to PDF only returns the first page, even if has multiple sheets.

```
 Excel::create('name', function ($excel) {
     foreach ($categories as $value) {
          $excel->sheet($value['name'], function($sheet) {
            ...
          });
     }
 })->download('pdf');
```

How can I see all pages?
I'm using laravel 4.2, maatwebsite/excel 1.3.0 and mpdf 6.0.0

Answer (score 2):

Fetch $data and put $filename = "new.pdf"

```
 $filename = "new.pdf";
 Excel::download( new ExportOrder( $data ), $filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [documentation](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export) you should use `->export('pdf')` instead of `->download('pdf')`.

Please try it and return with the result.

*Text from the documentation:

To export files to pdf, you will have to include "dompdf/dompdf": "~0.6.1", "mpdf/mpdf": "~5.7.3" or "tecnick.com/tcpdf": "~6.0.0" in your composer.json and change the export.pdf.driver config setting accordingly.*

Comment: I had already done , with the same result. Only shows the first page.

Comment: I tried dompdf/dompdf ~0.6.1, mpdf/mpdf ~5.7.3, mpdf/mpdf 6.0.0  and tecnick.com/tcpdf ~6.0.0. Same result. T_T

Comment: I don't think I can help you with this, I would probably use mpdf without maatwebsite. It got quite easy [documentation](http://mpdf1.com/manual/) and it will probably be faster to use less functions (only mpdf instead of both mpdf and maatwebsite).

Comment: That's what I'm going to do, make another report but now with mPHP for the php report. Thanks for answer.

Comment: I found [this issue](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/386) on github.

Comment: I have another (hopefully possible) solution, if you use the maatwebsite function `->store` instead (move the foreach outside the `Excel::create`), and then combine them with [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4795472/4637793), it could work? (it would probably take more time to download the pdf-report but it could be faster to write the code)

Answer (score 1):

I generate the same question on maatwebsite github. I did this and it works.

https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/386