# laravel :- unable to set different size for different pages for single pdf

Tags: php, css, laravel, pdf, dompdf

I am trying to set big height and width for the first page and the smaller size for other pages.

I am using **Thujohn\Pdf\PdfFacade** library in laravel.

below is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
            <?php
                $pageWt = $drawing_width + 200; //very large size
                $pageHt = $drawing_height + 200;//very large size
            ?>
            @page { size: <?= $pageWt ?>px <?= $pageHt ?>px; }
            @page rotate { size: 400px 500px; }
            .pgbrk {
                page : rotate;
                font-size: 70px;
                page-break-before: always;
            }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="<?= URL::to('drawings/getDrawing?filepath=' . $filepath) ?>">
            <div class="pgbrk">
  some data
            </div>
<img src="<?= URL::to('drawings/getDrawing?filepath=' . $filepath) ?>">
            <div class="pgbrk">
  some data
            </div>
<img src="<?= URL::to('drawings/getDrawing?filepath=' . $filepath) ?>">
            <div class="pgbrk">
  some data
            </div>
<img src="<?= URL::to('drawings/getDrawing?filepath=' . $filepath) ?>">
            <div class="pgbrk">
  some data
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But above code sets same size for all pages.

I am expecting different sizes for pdf pages.

Do am I missing something. Please help.

Comment: Where have you initialized $drawing_width and height?

Comment: I am passing filepath, drawing_width, drawing_height, some data from controller to view. and I know these have large number integer value.

Comment: try implementing inline style, instead of @page

Comment: Not working wven inline css

Comment: instead of embedding php code for height and width value, just hard code it for the time being, see if that works.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/  on this link example 29 gave this kind of functionality. but even this is not working when I add in page-break-before: always; css in index class. this example code is hard coded even that one too not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dompdf does not yet support named pages. To achieve this with dompdf you would have to generate each page separately then combine them using another tool such as [FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/) ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4795472/264628%7D), [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/), or one of the [many other options](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+combine+pdf+files).

There are also some efforts to build support for merging PDFs using dompdf (e.g. [this fork](https://github.com/craigfrancis/dompdf/tree/page-merge)).