# How to merge multiple PDF files to one one-page PDF in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a bulk of small pdf files of bar-code labels. Lets say 1/4 of A4 each. What I want to do is to merge them all together so I have 4 labels per page (labels stacked 2x2 on one page). So I can print them all at once.

Is it possible to combine pdf files like this in PHP? There are some PDF merge libraries out there but all examples are adding/removing whole pages.

Do you have any experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org) and [FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/).
A good demo to start is available [here](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/demos/thumbnails/). You just have to remove the drawing of borders and offsets.

Answer (score 0):

Ues fpdf class in your project.
[fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) 
this post can  help you to solve your problam
 [merge-pdf-files-with-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794435/merge-pdf-files-with-php)