# Pimcore how to create PDF and send via email

Tags: php, pimcore, pimcore-v5

Anybody can give us a hint how to treat this best, if this can be achieved with „standards“ of pimcore?
Render a PDF with dynamic content and merge it with a PDF which has legal information.
Then send final pdf via email.

The PDF should be able to designed with HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Web2Print Documents to create and render the first PDF with dynamic content. To modify the PDF afterwards, you can hook into the PDF generation process (Pimcore 4 example):

```
    \Pimcore::getEventManager()->attach("document.print.postPdfGeneration", function (\Zend_EventManager_Event $e) {
        $document = $e->getTarget();
        $pdf = $e->getParam("pdf");
```

Once you got that PDF, you can merge it with other PDFs like described here: [Merge PDF files with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794435/merge-pdf-files-with-php)

Sending it via email should be easy at this point.