# Appending PDF Files in PHP with Base64

Tags: php, pdf, base64, phpmailer, file-get-contents

I have a series of base64 PDF Files that I would like to merge together. Currently I am using file_get_contents() and with PHPMailer can attach each of them separately.

```
$woFile = file_get_contents($url);
$invoiceFile = file_get_contents($invPDF64);
$tsFile = file_get_contents($tsPDF64);
...
$mail->AddStringAttachment($woFile, "1.pdf", "base64", "application/pdf");
$mail->AddStringAttachment($invoiceFile, "2.pdf", "base64", "application/pdf");
$mail->AddStringAttachment($tsFile, "3.pdf", "base64", "application/pdf");
```

All the examples I've seen online such as FPDF require the file to be locally downloaded, at least from what I saw. Is there a way to append each of these PDF files into one, and then have that attached to the email?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you specifically need to merge the PDFs into one PDF, or if you just want one file.  Here are options for both:

1. If you want to *merge* all PDFs into a single PDF file, then this is a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794435/merge-pdf-files-with-php).  You mention not wanting to have a local file, but this may be an unreasonable constraint (e.g., memory issues with large PDFs).  Use temporary files as appropriate and clean up after yourself.
2. If you just want a single file, consider putting the files into a [ZIP archive](http://php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php) and sending that.  You might also like the [ZipStream library](https://github.com/maennchen/ZipStream-PHP) for this purpose.  Here's some minimal code using the native library:

   ```
   $attachmentArchiveFilename = tempnam('tmp', 'zip');
   $zip = new ZipArchve();

   # omitting error checking here; don't do it in production
   $zip->open($attachmentArchiveFilename, ZipArchve::OVERWRITE);
   $zip->addFromString('PDFs/first.pdf', $woFile);
   $zip->addFromString('PDFs/second.pdf', $invoiceFile);
   $zip->addFromString('PDFs/third.pdf', $tsFile);
   $zip->close();

   $mail->addAttachment($attachmentArchiveFilename, 'InvoicePDFs.zip');

   # be sure to unlink/delete/remove your temporary file
   unlink( $attachmentArchiveFilename );
   ```