# how to Merge Multiple PDF files in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-dompdf, pdfmerger

I'm using dompdf to generate pdfs and download it to computer in my Laravel.

now i need to select multiple ids and generate pdfs for them and merge it into one pdf.
for that i storing generated pdfs in storage folder.

how can get all related pdfs and merge?
in some cases I need to merge 20+ pdfs into one.

i need to merge all pdf file i generated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge PDF files with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4794435/8394877)