# Branding uploaded PDF documents in Drupal

Tags: drupal, pdf

I'm looking into doing something pretty clever with uploaded documents for a client website. The documents currently are created as PDF's and I tend to create front covers for them and apply them using Acrobat Pro.

I was wondering if there is a way with Drupal in which this can be done automatically? For example if the client uploads their PDF document it will automatically 'brand' up the document with a default front cover when uploaded into the website. Is this possible or has anyone done anything like this before?

I've never personally seen this done before but it was ran past me to see if something like this is possible!

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks,

C

Comment: Yes, it's entirely possible, but you're likely going to have to write the code. There are a number of PHP PDF libraries that'll let you append a page to an existing PDF. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713701/php-how-to-combine-merge-multiple-pdfs

Comment: Cheers ceejayoz. Proving to be not a simple task this one!